# cleanup improperly formatted csv file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am downloading a xlsx file from a sharepoint, and then convert it into a csv file. However, since the xlsx file contained empty columns that were not deleted, it exports those to a csv file like follows...

```
columnOne,columnTwo,columnThree,,,,
valueOne,,,,,,
,valueTwo,,,,,
,,valueThree,,,,
```

As you can see, Import-Csv cmdlet will fail with that file because of the extra null titles. I want to know how to count the extra commas at the end. The number of columns are always changing, and the name of the columns are also always changing. So we start the count based from the last non-null title number.

Right now, I'm doing the following...

```
$csvFileEdited = Get-Content $csvFile

$csvFileEdited[0] = $csvFileEdited[0].TrimEnd(',')

$csvFileEdited | Set-Content "$csvFile-temp"
Move-Item "$csvFile-temp" $csvFile -Force
Write-Host "Trim Complete."
```

This will make the file output like this...

```
columnOne,columnTwo,columnThree
valueOne,,,,,,
,valueTwo,,,,,
,,valueThree,,,,
```

The naming is now accepted for Import-Csv, but as you can see there is still extra null values that are not necessary since they are null for every row.

If I did the following code...

```
$csvFileWithExtraCommas = Get-Content $csvFile
$csvFileWithoutExtraCommas = @()

FOrEach ($line in $csvFileWithExtraCommas)
{
    $line = $line.TrimEnd(',')
    $csvFileWithoutExtraCommas += $line
{

$csvFileWithoutExtraCommas | Set-Content "$csvFile-temp"
Move-Item "$csvFile-temp" $csvFile -Force
Write-Host "Trim Complete."
```

Then it would remove a null value that should be null because it belongs to a non-null title-name. Such is the output....

```
columnOne,columnTwo,columnThree
valueOne
,valueTwo
,,valueThree
```

Here is the desired output:

```
columnOne,columnTwo,columnThree
valueOne,,
,valueTwo,
,,valueThree
```

Can anyone help with this?

## Update

I'm using the following code to count the extra null titles...

```
$csvFileWithCommas = Get-Content $csvFile

[int]$csvFileWithExtraCommasNumber = $csvFileWithCommas[0].Length

$csvFileTitlesWithoutExtraCommas = $csvFileWithCommas[0].TrimEnd(',')

[int]$csvFileWithoutExtraCommasNumber = $csvFileTitlesWithoutExtraCommas.Length

$numOfCommas = $csvFileWithExtraCommasNumber - $csvFileWithoutExtraCommasNumber
```

The output of value of `$numOfCommas` is `4`. Now the question is how can I use $line.TrimEnd(',') to only do so 4 times??

Comment: @SemihOzmen The OP has shown effort and a pretty good MCVE from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.... If you really need to do this you can count the trailing commas from the header and use regex to remove as many the from the end of each line. There are other string manipulation approaches but the regex in this case is pretty clean.

**Note** that what [Bluecakes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424971/3829407) shows should suffice. Perhaps there is some other hidden characters that are not being copied in the question or perhaps an encoding issue with your real file.

```
$file = Get-Content "D:\temp\text.csv"
# Number of trailing commas. Compare the length before and after the trim
$numberofcommas = $file[0].Length - $file[0].TrimEnd(",").Length
# Use regex to remove as many commas from the end of each line and convert to csv object.
$file -replace ",{$numberofcommas}$" | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Regex is looking for X commas at the end of of each line where X is `$numberofcommas`. In our case it would look like `,{4}$`

---

Source file used with above code was generated as such

```
@"
columnOne,columnTwo,columnThree,,,,
valueOne,,,,,,
,valueTwo,,,,,
,,valueThree,,,,
"@ | set-content D:\temp\text.csv
```

Comment: This seams more logical, I'm not familiar with convertfrom-csv, and it's giving errors, but I think I can change it a bit if the `$file -replace ",{$numberofcommas}$"` is correct. I'll confirm the answer in a few moments. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: I am using PowerShell v4 if it matters but it should not for this. Also test with the data you used in the question to see if the logic holds. Could be some extra characters we don't see. If you get errors would be nice to know what they are.

Comment: Yup, it's working, just had to change the last line in your code to this `$file = $file -replace ",{$numberofcommas}$"` and `$file | Set-Content "$file-temp.csv"`. The 4 commas are removed from every line as wanted. Thanks a bunch :D

Comment: I think that means that `($file -replace ",{$numberofcommas}$") | ConvertFrom-Csv` would have worked. @FiddleFreak

Comment: Yup, it worked :) Mixing get-content and import-csv is tricky, so I gotta keep those cmdlets seperate :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting an error when trying to `Import-csv`? The cmdlet is smart enough to ignore columns without a heading without any additional code needed.

I copied your csv file to my H:\ drive:

```
columnOne,columnTwo,columnThree,,,,
valueOne,,,,,,
,valueTwo,,,,,
,,valueThree,,,,
```

and then ran `$nullcsv = Import-Csv -Path H:\nullcsv.csv` and this is what i got

```
PS> $nullcsv

columnOne columnTwo columnThree
--------- --------- -----------
valueOne
          valueTwo
                    valueThree
```

The imported csv only contains 3 values as you would expect:

```
PS> $nullcsv.count
3
```

The cmdlet is also orrectly accounting for null values in each of the columns:

```
PS> $nullcsv | Format-List

columnOne   : valueOne
columnTwo   :
columnThree :

columnOne   :
columnTwo   : valueTwo
columnThree :

columnOne   :
columnTwo   :
columnThree : valueThree
```

Comment: This was also my findings.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting an error `Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid.` I found a way to count the commas, now I just need to know how to apply that count to `TrimEnd`

Comment: @FiddleFreak Is that the error you get with your test data that you have in the question?

Comment: Yes, i also found articles where people were getting the same error and they had to remove the null titles (they do this manually). My script should do this automatically and this is what I'm trying to figure out. I updated the question with some extra findings. Btw, what ps version are you using Bluecakes?